# Python run loop until keyword is found inside list selenium element

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, selenium, if-statement

I have a list of elements  they return like this

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d3cf9b70-cdc1-11e7-8b3e-570f82e3aaae", element=":wdc:1511161807512")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d3cf9b70-cdc1-11e7-8b3e-570f82e3aaae", element=":wdc:1511161807513")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d3cf9b70-cdc1-11e7-8b3e-570f82e3aaae", element=":wdc:1511161807514")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d3cf9b70-cdc1-11e7-8b3e-570f82e3aaae", element=":wdc:1511161807515")>
```

How I collect them

```
for comment in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '﻿')]"):
```

Inside the elements there is text I can see the text like this

```
print(comment.text)
```

how do I run the loop until I have found a keyword inside of the elements list?

For example the keyword could be "LakerKobe". If it finds the element with the text of the keyword I set, I want the loop to stop running.

This is what I thought would work

```
for comment in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '﻿')]"):
    if 'LakerKobe' in comment.text:
        print('found')
```

However this method is unreliable. It works & sometimes it doesn't. For example if you run this

```
keywordMain = 'if you shoot heroin 90% chance your dead already. herion is a different beast﻿'

if 'heroin﻿' in keywordMain:
        print('found')
```

you will see nothing is returned. I am using python 3.6

Comment: I still need help

Comment: Can you update with the status with my Answer? Are you seeing any error or any deviation from the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

As you are collecting the `WebElements` through :

```
for comment in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '')]"):
```

To print `Search Found` when one of the `WebElements` contains the string `LakerKobe` you can use the following code block :

```
for comment in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '')]"):
    if ("LakerKobe" in comment.get_attribute('innerHTML')):
        print("Search Found")
```

### Update :

As an alternative you can try out this option as well :

```
for comment in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '')]"):
    if comment.get_attribute('innerHTML').__contains__('LakerKobe'):
        print("Search Found")
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for... I'm not looking at innerHTML they're sentences in each element

Comment: @FutureHendrixs Did you at least try out the code once, though it may sound different from your understanding?

Comment: Yeah bro. Do you got any other ways

Comment: @FutureHendrixs What deviation do you observe in the actual result with respect to the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Both words ("heroin" in `for` loop and "heroin" in `keywordMain`) are seem to be equal, but they not. Try

```
[ord(i) for i in "heroin"]
```

for both words and you'll get

```
[104, 101, 114, 111, 105, 110]
```

and

```
[104, 101, 114, 111, 105, 110, 239, 187, 191]
```

appropriately. There are few extra ASCII characters in word you used in `for` loop.

So it's not about Selenium. Just use exact keyword

Comment: where exactly would `[ord(i) for i in "heroin"]` go? What is it doing

Comment: It just turn the string into ASCII code. You can simply do `"heroin" == "heroin"` to see that these are different words

Answer (score 0):

**Try to print**

```
print 'heroin﻿'.__repr__()  #copy exactly from if condition 
print keywordMain[3].__repr__()

#you will see extra characters which is hidden but makes string different.
'heroin\xef\xbb\xbf'
'heroin'
```

> you can get rid of that character using this simple method.

```
def remove_non_asciis(s):
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: ord(x)<128, s))
```